# Unwanted gap in the rightmost column in CSS grid layout

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a grid template layout but a strange column gap keeps appearing on the rightmost side. How do I remove this?

I have included the link of the issue (see the extra column gap on the right) https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPKNU.png

Here is my HTML and CSS code:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1920px;
  margin: auto;
}

.img-gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-column-gap: 30px;
  grid-template-areas: 'img-1 img-2 img-3';
}

.img-gallery div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="img-gallery">
    <div class="img-1" style="background-image: url(images/img-1);"></div>
    <div class="img-2" style="background-image: url(images/img-2);"></div>
    <div class="img-3" style="background-image: url(images/img-3);"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried that by an image address from myself and it works fine. Doesn't exist an Unwanted gap in the rightmost column. I also removed some codes that you don't need to them in your code (They have been commented):

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1920px;
  margin: auto;
}

.img-gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-column-gap: 30px;
  /*
  grid-template-areas: 'img-1 img-2 img-3';
  */
}

.img-gallery div {
  height: 300px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  /*
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="img-gallery">
    <div class="img-1" style="background-image: url('https://s4.uupload.ir/files/1-6-5_ssnb.jpg');"></div>
    <div class="img-2" style="background-image: url('https://s4.uupload.ir/files/1-6-5_ssnb.jpg');"></div>
    <div class="img-3" style="background-image: url('https://s4.uupload.ir/files/1-6-5_ssnb.jpg');"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code and I couldn't find any issue.

please check the below code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    .container {
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 1920px;
      margin: auto;
    }
    
    .img-gallery {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
      grid-template-rows: auto;
      grid-column-gap: 30px;
      grid-template-areas: 'img-1 img-2 img-3';
    }
    
    .img-gallery div {
      width: 100%;
      height: 300px;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      position: relative;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="img-gallery">
      <div class="img-1" style="background-color: red;"></div>
      <div class="img-2 " style="background-color: green;"></div>
      <div class="img-3" style="background-color: yellow;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```